# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied - Parameter is in stored procedure(I think)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, web

I've encountered an error which is absolutely driving me insane. Forgive me, I'm a novice, so I may be missing something out which is stupid or silly so sorry in advance.

I keep getting the error

> "Procedure or function 'prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdAppointmentSelect' expects parameter '@PatientNumber', which was not supplied."

This is baffling to me as '@PatientNumber' is in the stored procedure but my knowledge of SQL isn't the greatest.

***ASPX Code***

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlResults" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" >
                <asp:GridView ID="gvAppointmentSearch" runat="server" Font-Names = "Arial" 
                    Font-Size = "11pt" ForeColor = "#000000"
                    onselectedindexchanged="gvAppointmentSearch_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" DataKeyNames="PatientNumber" AllowPaging = "true"
                    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" PageSize = "10" Width = "100%" 
                    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "#465c71" HeaderStyle-ForeColor = "#ffffff" 
                    style="margin-bottom: 26px"> 

                    <Columns>
                        <%--Creates a select button that appear at the start of the grid view--%>
                       <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Appointment Number" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--This will be the first field to appear beside the select button--%>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAppointmentNumber" Text='<%# Eval("AppointmentNumber") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--Bound fields will place them in a specific order--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "AppointmentDate" HeaderText = "Appointment Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "AppointmentTime" HeaderText = "Appointment Time" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "Consultant" HeaderText="Referred By" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField = "ByAttendance" HeaderText="Attendance"/>
                    </Columns> 
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvAppointmentSearch" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

***C# Code***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populate dropdown if no record has been selected
            String strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConString);
            conn.ConnectionString = strConString;
            SqlCommand cmdInit = new SqlCommand();
            cmdInit.CommandText = "Select * from DropdownCounty";
            cmdInit.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dtInit = new DataTable();
            dtInit.Load(cmdInit.ExecuteReader());
            conn.Close();
            dpdCounty.DataSource = dtInit;
            dpdCounty.DataTextField = "County";
            dpdCounty.DataValueField = "CountyID";
            dpdCounty.DataBind();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = (DataSet)Session["DS"];
            this.DataBindSearch();

            try
            {
                //Fields that are required to be filled in if the information is avaliable
                patientNumber.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PatientNumber"].ToString();
                txtHCNumber.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["HC_Number"].ToString();
                //if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentToDatabase"].ToString() != null)
                //chkDBConsent.Checked = (bool)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentToDatabase"];

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentGivenDate"].ToString() != "dd/mm/yyyy")
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentGivenDate"].ToString() != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentGivenDate"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        ConsentGivenDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ConsentGivenDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
                    }
                }
                IDnumberLegacy.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID_Number_LegacyID"].ToString();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sex"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    //Datasource is added only when values are being added to allow for alterations to be made 
                    //Allows for records with older dropdown values no longer selectable to be visible
                    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                    con.ConnectionString = strConnString;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlCommand cmdPop = new SqlCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "Select Sex from DropdownSex";

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    con.Close();

                    //String builder to gather records that are currently active
                    StringBuilder currentid = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

                        currentid.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray));
                    }

                    //convert stringbuilder to string
                    var output = currentid.ToString();

                    // Creates new StringReader instance from System.IO
                    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(output))
                    {
                        // Loop over the lines in the string.
                        int count = 0;
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            count++;

                            if (line == (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sex"].ToString()))
                                cmdPop.CommandText = " Select * From DropdownSex";
                        }
                    }

                    if (cmdPop.CommandText == "")
                        cmdPop.CommandText = " Select * From DropdownSex";

                    cmdPop.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtValues = new DataTable();
                    dtValues.Load(cmdPop.ExecuteReader());
                    con.Close();
                    dpdSex.DataSource = dtValues;
                    dpdSex.DataTextField = "Sex";
                    dpdSex.DataValueField = "SexID";
                    dpdSex.DataBind();
                    dpdSex.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SexID"].ToString();
                }
                txtPatientFirstName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Forename"].ToString();
                txtPatientSurname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Surname"].ToString();
                PatientMaiden.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MaidenName"].ToString();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString() != "dd/mm/yyyy")
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString() != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        txtDateOfBirth.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateOfBirth"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
                    }
                }
                AddressLine1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine1"].ToString();
                AddressLine2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine2"].ToString();
                AddressLine3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine3_TownCity"].ToString();
                AddressLine4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AddressLine4_Region"].ToString();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["County"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    //Datasource is added only when values are being added to allow for alterations to be made 
                    //Allows for records with older dropdown values no longer selectable to be visible
                    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                    con.ConnectionString = strConnString;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    SqlCommand cmdPop = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select County from DropdownCounty";

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    con.Close();

                    //String builder to gather records that are currently active
                    StringBuilder currentid = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

                        currentid.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dr.ItemArray));
                    }

                    //convert stringbuilder to string
                    var output = currentid.ToString();

                    // Creates new StringReader instance from System.IO
                    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(output))
                    {
                        // Loop over the lines in the string.
                        int count = 0;
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            count++;

                            if (line == (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["County"].ToString()))
                                cmdPop.CommandText = " Select * From DropdownCounty";
                        }
                    }

                    if (cmdPop.CommandText == "")
                        cmdPop.CommandText = " Select * From DropdownCounty";

                    cmdPop.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtValues = new DataTable();

                    dtValues.Load(cmdPop.ExecuteReader());
                    con.Close();
                    dpdCounty.DataSource = dtValues;
                    dpdCounty.DataTextField = "County";
                    dpdCounty.DataValueField = "CountyID";
                    dpdCounty.DataBind();
                    dpdCounty.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CountyID"].ToString();
                }
                PostCode.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PostCode"].ToString();
                HomeTelNumber.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["HomeTelNumber"].ToString();
                MobileTelNumber.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MobileTelNumber"].ToString();
                WorkTelNumber.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WorkTelNumber"].ToString();
                PatientEmail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
                PatientNotes.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
                //Sets the color of the text box depedning if a value has been entered
                string hex = "#F0F8FF";
                if (txtDateOfBirth.Text != "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    txtDateOfBirth.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                else
                    txtDateOfBirth.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);

                if (ConsentGivenDate.Text != "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    ConsentGivenDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                else
                    ConsentGivenDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
            }

            //If the dataset is empty this is executed instead
            catch (Exception fe)
            {
                lblErrors.Text = "New Record Successfully Started!";

                //calls the poup to display a notification
                dvMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;
            }
        }
        //Not required as this label has been replaced with a popup, still used to store message that will be displayed
        lblErrors.Visible = true;
        //Load the initial data from the session once
        //***Custom error messages below***//
        //Used to pull error message if someone else has already updated the data first
        if (Session["ex"] != null)
        {
            var msg = Session["ex"].ToString();
            //Message to be displayed
            if (msg == "Error")
                lblErrors.Text = "Update Failed! Someone has already made changes!";
            else
                lblErrors.Text = "Unable to update HC Number!";

            //calls the popup to display a notification
            dvMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;

            //required to prevent error message appearing everytime the page loads
            Session["ex"] = null;
        }

        //As the page refreshes when a new record is added to allow the master page to display the new records details this is required to pull
        //forward the success message to inform the user that the record has been added and the page has not just refreshed
        if (Session["NewRecordAdded"] != null)
        {
            //Message to be displayed
            lblErrors.Text = "Record Succesfully Added!";

            //calls the popup to display a notification
            dvMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;

            //required to prevent error message appearing everytime the page loads
            Session["NewRecordAdded"] = null;
        }

        //Error when trying to find record that does not exist
        if (Session["FindRecordError"] != null)
        {
            string a = Session["FindRecordError"].ToString();
            //Message to be displayed
            if (a == "Unable to locate")
                lblErrors.Text = "Unable to find record!";
            else
                lblErrors.Text = "Full HC Number required!";

            //calls the popup to display a notification
            dvMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;

            //required to prevent error message appearing everytime the page loads
            Session["FindRecordError"] = null;
        }

        if (Session["PersonalDeatilsSave"] != null)
        {
            //only if an update has occured
            lblErrors.Text = "Save Successful!";

            //calls the popup to display a notification
            dvMsg.Visible = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "" + lblErrors.Text;

            //required to prevent error message appearing everytime the page loads
            Session["PersonalDeatilsSave"] = null;
        }
    }

    protected void gvAppointmentSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int index = gvAppointmentSearch.SelectedIndex;

        string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString);
        myConnect.ConnectionString = strConString;

        string strCommandText = "prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdAppointmentRetrieve";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatientNumber", gvAppointmentSearch.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()));

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "personal");

            //Needed to reset the clinical eval page for newly selected patient
            Session["NDS"] = null;
        }

        catch (Exception fe)
        {
            lblMoreErrors.Text = "Error: " + fe.Message;
        }

        try
        {
            //Assigns the selected patients details to the dataset and redirects the user to the personal page
            Session["DS"] = ds;
            Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/PatientAppointment.aspx");
        }

        catch (Exception er)
        {
            lblErrors.Text = "Error: " + er.Message;
        }
    }

    //Tells the gridview what to do when the page change is selected
    protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBindSearch();
        gvAppointmentSearch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvAppointmentSearch.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DataBindSearch()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString);
        myConnect.ConnectionString = strConString;
        string strCommandText = "prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdAppointmentSelect";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "personal");

            gvAppointmentSearch.DataSource = ds;
            //Finally, all results matching the criteria will be placed into the gridview
            gvAppointmentSearch.DataBind();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Session["CurrentData"] = dt;
            //Counts the number of results found
            lblResults.Text = "Results Found: " + ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sum(x => x.Rows.Count).ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception fe)
        {
            lblErrors.Text = "Error: " + fe.Message;
        }
    }

    }
```

***SQL Stored Procedure***

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdAppointmentSelect]
@PatientNumber int
AS
SELECT 
[dbo].[Appointments].[AppointmentDate] as AppointmentDate
,dbo.Appointments.AppointmentTime as AppointmentTime
,[dbo].[DropdownReferredBy].[ReferredBy] as Consultant
,[dbo].[DropdownAttended].[ByAttendance] as ByAttendance
,dbo.Appointments.AppointmentNumber as AppointmentNumber
  FROM [dbo].[PATIENTS] 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Appointments on dbo.PATIENTS.PatientNumber = dbo.Appointments.PatientNumber
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DropdownReferredBy] on dbo.Appointments.ReferredBy = [dbo].[DropdownReferredBy].ReferredBy
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DropdownAttended] on dbo.Appointments.ByAttendance = dbo.DropdownAttended.ByAttendance

  WHERE dbo.PATIENTS.PatientNumber LIKE @PatientNumber

  ORDER BY AppointmentNumber ASC;
```

To add to all this, this page takes its data from another gridview with a connecting stored procedure.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I've done something very silly!!!

Answer (score 2):

In your DataBindSearch() method, you are not providing a value for the @PatientNumber parameter.  You need to specify that parameter and give it a value like you do further up in your code.

Also, while I have your attention, you should really be putting your SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects in `using` statements.

```
protected void DataBindSearch()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OepdSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string strCommandText = "prcPersonalSelectedByPatientIdAppointmentSelect";

    using (SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, connect))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //You need to add the parameter before you call da.Fill()
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatientNumber", /*Parameter Value*/));

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
            da.Fill(ds, "personal");

            gvAppointmentSearch.DataSource = ds;
            //Finally, all results matching the criteria will be placed into the gridview
            gvAppointmentSearch.DataBind();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            Session["CurrentData"] = dt;
            //Counts the number of results found
            lblResults.Text = "Results Found: " + ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sum(x => x.Rows.Count).ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception fe)
        {
            lblErrors.Text = "Error: " + fe.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Hill thanks for your answer - however - I'm getting an error at     sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PatientNumber", gvAppointmentSearch.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString())); as its saying that "The name 'index' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @karlb123 My bad, I've edited my answer.  You need to replace that part of the line with whatever you want `PatientNumber` to be

Comment: I think your original answer is correct as its calling the data from SQL to create a gridview on page load. However its just not working unfortunately

Comment: The fact that you weren't providing a value for that parameter is definitely what the problem is.  What that value is or where you get is something you need to figure out, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help - my brain finally figured out why it wasn't working. I was trying to search an index which hadn't been called yet